# HTMX - window.location.href returns previous URL link

Tags: htmx

I'm trying to acces the current URL in my project but it's only returning the previous URL.

Here is what I have:

```
htmx.onLoad(function(content) {
    console.log(window.location.href);
})
```

Any idea how to get the current URL after issuing an HTMX request?

Comment: Have you used the `hx-push-url="true"` attribute on the original element or the corresponding `HX-Push` response header to make HTMX update the history?

Comment: Yes I have. The URL changes everytime i switch links but my console returns the URL where I was coming from and not the current one

Comment: It seems that HTMX has a specific event for [history updates](https://htmx.org/events/#htmx:pushedIntoHistory). Try to attach the event listener to it via `htmx.on("htmx:pushedIntoHistory", ...`

Comment: Thanks Again @Dauros! You should add this as a response so I can select it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTMX emits the [`htmx:pushedIntoHistory`](https://htmx.org/events/#htmx:pushedIntoHistory) event after it pushed the new URL to the history. You can attach an event listener to it by:

```
htmx.on("htmx:pushedIntoHistory", function(event) {
    console.log(window.location.href)
})
```